# On clicking an acronym, go to the first instance, not the table of acronyms

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package together with `hyperref`, but I realize that I don't need the table of acronyms. Rather, I would prefer that on clicking an acronym, I want to reach the first instance of `\gls{myacronym}`. Is there anyway to do that.

Thank you

Edit: Added sample code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5 in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{acr}{myacr}{My Acronym}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} 
I refer to the acronym here \acrfull{acr}. Since, I don't have a list of acryonyms, on clicking the acronym link I want to go to the section where the acronym is explained.

\pagebreak

\section{Chapter on My Acronym}
\gls{acr} is explained here in detail. On clicking an occurrence, the reader should be directed here.
\end{document}
```

Edit 2:
Some users have marked this question as a duplicate, but it's not. My question is that any occurrence of an acronym should link to it's first occurrence, rather than the list of acronyms. In contrast, the "other" question asks about linking the first occurrence with the list of acronyms.

Comment: As always on this site, posting a full but minimal example that others can copy and test, greatly increade your chances of getting help.

Comment: Ok, let me do that.

Comment: Please see the code @daleif

Comment: @Troy,  Question is not duplicate, please see Edit 2

Comment: In my earlier comment (which has been deleted) I thought it was this was possibly a duplicate of [Glossaries: Hyperlink to First Entry not List of Acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140666) but it seems that it was closed as a duplicate of another question. Can you confirm whether or not [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145782/19862) solves your problem?

Comment: This is what I was asking. Thank you very much.