# Glossaries: Hyperlink to First Entry in a chapter not List of Acronyms

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

Is it possible to direct the hyperlink created by `\gls{term}` to the first use of the term in the chapter instead of the glossary list?

A similar topic was discussed in: [Glossaries: Hyperlink to First Entry not List of Acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140666/glossaries-hyperlink-to-first-entry-not-list-of-acronyms)
However, when I used that solution all the links were redirecting to the first appearance in the text. For example an acronym in chapter 5 would link me to the abstract.

The following is an example of the code I'm currently using to set-up the glossaries and `hyperref` packages and define a term:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\preto\chapter{\glsresetall}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{nohyperfirst}{true}
\renewcommand*{\glsdonohyperlink}[2]{%
 {\glsxtrprotectlinks 
   \edef\fieldvalue{\glsxtrusefield{\glslabel}{hastarget}}%
   \ifdefstring\fieldvalue{true}
   {%
     #2%
   }%
   {%
     \gGlsXtrSetField{\glslabel}{hastarget}{true}\glsdohypertarget{#1}{#2}%
   }%
 }%
}

\newacronym{FEA}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

First use: \gls{FEA}. %No hyperlink

Next use: \gls{FEA}. %Redirecting to First use.

\chapter{Literature review}

Third use: \gls{FEA}. %No hyperlink

Fourth use: \gls{FEA}. %Wish to redirect to Third use, but it is going to First use.

\end{document}
```